# Write "If Then Else" in a single line

Tags: line-breaking, algorithmicx

Is it possible to have "if .. then .. else" in a single line?

I am looking for ways to condense simple conditional statements that is taking much space in my write-up. So, any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
    \title{HOWTO Single Line If Then Else}
    \author{Author}
    \maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    This is an abstract.
\end{abstract}

\hspace{10pt}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
    a, b, c, d.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Single line IF THEN ELSE}\label{alg:IfThenElse}
    {\fontsize{8}{8}\selectfont
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \If {$\text{foo} \leq \text{bar}$} $doh$ = 0
            \Else {} $\text{duh}$ = 1
            \EndIf
        \end{algorithmic}
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fairly elementary (but effective) way of achieving this is to use `\IfThenElse{<if>}{<then>}{<else>}` defined by

```
\algnewcommand{\IfThenElse}[3]{% \IfThenElse{<if>}{<then>}{<else>}
  \State \algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen\ #2\ \algorithmicelse\ #3}
```

It just sets a `\State` with all the components needed right next to one another.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand{\IfThenElse}[3]{% \IfThenElse{<if>}{<then>}{<else>}
  \State \algorithmicif\ #1\ \algorithmicthen\ #2\ \algorithmicelse\ #3}

\begin{document}

\title{HOWTO Single Line If Then Else}
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
a, b, c, d.
\end{IEEEkeywords}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Single line IF THEN ELSE}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If {$\text{foo} \leq \text{bar}$} $\text{doh} = 0$
    \Else {} $\text{duh} = 1$
    \EndIf
    \IfThenElse {$\text{foo} \leq \text{bar}$}% If ...
      {$\text{doh} = 0$}% ...then...
      {$\text{duh} = 1$}% ...else...
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```